# SSH X11 forwarding with port forwarding

Tags: linux, ssh, x11, port-forwarding

I have one question about SSH X11 forwarding and Port forwarding.

I have:

- 2 computers running Ubuntu Desktop (not in the same location and local network) called `Desktop1` with IP address `IP1`, the other is `Desktop2`, `IP2`.
- and 1 VPS (Ubuntu Server) with IP address `IP_VPS`.

`D1 <------> VPS <------> D2`

In `Desktop1`, I ran this command:

`ssh -XC -R 8022:localhost:22 vps_user@IP_VPS`

Then, I ran these command on `Desktop2`:

`ssh -XC vps_user@IP_VPS`

On connected SSH shell, I ran:

`ssh -XC desktop_user@localhost -p 8022`

(The purpose is to connect to `Desktop1` from `Desktop2` via `VPS`)

I connected to `Desktop1` successfully. But when I tried to run a GUI app on the connected SSH shell like: `gedit`, the window didn't appear in `Desktop2` but in `Desktop1`. I was expected it to be forwarded to `Desktop2`.

Please explain to me that I am misunderstanding something? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu may be using Wayland instead of X11, which would make the X11 forwarding not apply.

Since the purpose of the `ssh` command on Desktop1 is just to establish a remote-to-local port forwarding to allow a future inbound connection, you don't need X11 forwarding options on that connection at all. But that should have caused no harm.

Otherwise, your commands seem essentially correct: an X11 application should have either displayed its window on Desktop2 or reported an error of `$DISPLAY` not being defined.

The only way an **X11** GUI app started on the VPS->Desktop1 SSH session would have displayed on Desktop1 itself would be if something had explicitly set `DISPLAY=:0` on Desktop1 before starting the X11 app. (Since `desktop_user@Desktop1` presumably already had a local GUI session open for the first SSH connection, desktop_user already had a valid session cookie for the local X11 display.)

But this is only true **if Desktop1 is actually configured to use X11 in the first place**. Ubuntu's GNOME desktop [may be using Wayland](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/), which cuts off the X11 protocol entirely: if `gedit` is using the Wayland protocol instead of X11, then the `DISPLAY` variable would be meaningless for it, and it would display on Desktop1's local display instead.

I've understood that in Wayland, shared memory buffers between the client, the display compositor (the closest equivalent of the X11 server) and the kernel/display hardware are not optional, therefore the Wayland protocol does not allow remoting the application like X11 does. GUI remoting solutions like VNC or RDP could be implemented separately on Wayland.

Perhaps test with an actual X11-only application, like `xterm`? Or configure the GUI on Desktop1 to X11-only mode, by finding the commented-out line `#WaylandEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`, uncommenting it, and then rebooting Desktop1.

(More info on disabling Wayland on Ubuntu here: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop )

Comment: I disabled Wayland on Desktop1, then tried again. On Desktop2's taskbar there is Gedit icon, but the window still didn't show. Then, I disabled Wayland in Desktop2 too and everything works as expected! Thank you very much!